# Odoo Create Read Only Model without Saving It in Database

Tags: database, odoo, odoo-14

I want to create a computed field for One2many field in contact module (`res.partner`). This is my field declaration

```
payments = fields.One2many('payment', 'partner_id')
```

I add a compute attribute, so `payments` field calculated automatically

```
payments = fields.One2many('payment', 'partner_id', compute='_compute_payments')
```

This is my computed method

```
def _compute_payments(self):
    for rec in self:
        ... # Do some query on database
        ... # Do some query on database

        rec.payments = self.env['payments'].create({
            'partner_id': rec.id,
            ... # Another field with value from query
            ... # Another field with value from query
        })
```

Everything is okay, but when I check the database, the record is being created over and over again. **I don't want to save the records on the database**, just like another field with compute attribute didn't stored on the database in default mode.

Comment: Computed fields are not stored by default, they are computed and returned when requested. Every time the field is recomputed, the `_compute_payments` function will create a new payment for each record in self.

Comment: Yes I know if the field is simple like Char, Boolean, Integer, etc the data will not stored on database

Comment: All computed fields,  not only the basic fields

Comment: You can try my example, and you will see a lot of duplicate data

Comment: The compute method call the create method which will add payments to the database each time it is called by Odoo (computed and returned when requested).